# Django-Page not found

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm a real newbie to Django, (following tutorial in openclassroom)

I have a django project called "blog", the code in the file "urls.py" of the main DjangoProject is this:

[DjangoProject\urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt2G0.png)

The code in blog\urls is this:

[blog\urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMjS6.png)

When I run the server, I get this:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CWgj.png)

Help is very much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your project urls.py you should change this path('blog/') to this path('') as in your case you do not have configured the path ('/') on your project urls so the / is not found because the blog is linked to localhost:8000/blog url

Comment: Here's my installed apps code: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
]

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: glad it helped, keep grinding with django it is an awesome framework

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your URL configurations. You are navigating to https://127.0.0.1:8000/, but this is not a URL you have defined. Your available URL paths are https://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ and https://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/. Navigate to https://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ and it should be working.

Or make the following change to your DjangoProject/urls.py:

```
path('', include ('blog.urls'))
```

Hope this helps.